# c# Task do not work without sleep between them

Tags: c#, multithreading, task

I'm using Task in c# to send file via FTP in multithread.

here is my function (file is a list of strings)

```
 Task<bool>[] result = new Task<bool>[file.Count];
        int j = 0;
        foreach (string f in file)
        {  
            result[j] = new Task<bool>(() => ftp.UploadFtp(f, "C:\\Prova\\" + f + ".txt", j));
            result[j].Start();
            j++;

            //System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(50);

        }
        Task.WaitAll(result, 10000);
```

and the function to upload files

```
public static bool UploadFtp(string uploadFileName, string localFileName, int i)
    {
        FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("ftp://127.0.0.1/" + uploadFileName + ".txt");
        //settare il percorso per il file da uplodare
        //FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("ftp://desk.txt.it/");
        request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;

        request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("ftp_admin", "");
        //request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("avio", "avio_txt");
        try
        {
            Console.WriteLine(uploadFileName);
            Console.WriteLine(i);
            StreamReader sourceStream = new StreamReader(localFileName);
            byte[] fileContents = File.ReadAllBytes(localFileName);

            sourceStream.Close();
            request.ContentLength = fileContents.Length;

            Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();
            requestStream.Write(fileContents, 0, fileContents.Length);
            requestStream.Close();

            FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

            //MessageBox.Show("Upload File Complete, status {0}", response.StatusDescription);

            response.Close();
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return false;
        }

    }
```

in this way the program try always to save the last file of the list, but if I add a Sleep(50) it uploads the files correctly.
it seems that the program starts 4 task doing the same job (saving the last file) only if I do not use sleep, but I do not understand why and I don't know how to solve the problem.

Can someone help me? thank you

Comment: Try adding a `string localCopy = f;` statement to your loop, and use `localCopy` instead of `f`. I suspect you are encountering the dreaded loop closure problem, where you always get the last reference assigned to `f` because of the closure mechanics.

Comment: Note that your `UploadFtp` method is not very async-friendly - the IO could be made async to allow for much better scaling when uploading many files.

Comment: This is a perfect example of why, even though async development is getting easier, there are still pitfalls involved that need to be understood to do it correctly.  Fortunately it usually only takes doing this wrong once before learning the lesson.  I know this first hand since I did this same thing myself before I knew any better :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Look at your code:

```
int j = 0;
foreach (string f in file)
{  
    result[j] = new Task<bool>(() => ftp.UploadFtp(f, "C:\\Prova\\" + f + ".txt", j));
    result[j].Start();
    j++;
}
```

The lambda expression uses the *current value of `j`* whenever it's executed. So if the task starts *after* the `j` is incremented, you'll miss the value you intended.

In C# 4, you have the same problem with `f` - but this has been fixed in C# 5. See Eric Lippert's blog post ["Closing over the loop variable considered harmful"](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/11/12/closing-over-the-loop-variable-considered-harmful.aspx) for more details.

The smallest fix is trivial:

```
int j = 0;
foreach (string f in file)
{  
    int copyJ = j;
    string copyF = f;
    result[j] = new Task<bool>(
         () => ftp.UploadFtp(copyF, "C:\\Prova\\" + copyF + ".txt", copyJ));
    result[j].Start();
    j++;
}
```

Now nothing will change `copyJ` and `copyF` - you'll get a separate variable being captured in each iteration of the loop. In C# 5, you don't need `copyF`, and can just use `f` instead.

... but I'd also suggest using `Task.Factory.StartNew()`, (or `Task.Run` in .NET 4.5) or just `Parallel.For`.

Comment: @Jon Do you really need a copy of `j`?  You are setting it but not using it.

Comment: @Jon Oh...and congratulations on hitting half million reputation points!

Comment: no j was just something I used to undestand better the error, I'm not using it

Comment: @GeneS: It was a typo - I was using `copy` instead of `copyJ`. See the diff in the edit. (It was right before I realized that `f` needed copying too :)

Comment: @Jon But since `j` is an int won't it be passed by value anyways?  Or is it just safer to create a copy in all cases?

Comment: @GeneS: It would be passed by value whether it was an int or anything else... but that's just the call to `ftp.UploadFtp`. The *arguments* for that are still evaluated when the task starts. Read the blog post I linked to - that should make it clearer.